# Display images datagrid template field in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, wpfdatagrid

How to display images (stored in SQL database) to an image control in template field of datagrid in WPF using LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 1):

The classes generated by Linq are Partial.  This allows you to extend them.  So, assuming that you're link class has a property along the following lines:

```
public byte[] Image {get; set;}
```

you can add to the partial class with a property like this

```
public ImageSource imageSource
{
    get
    {
            var Img = new BitmapImage();
            Img.BeginInit();
            Img.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream((byte[])Image);
            Img.EndInit();
            return Img;
     }
 }
```

Then in the template for you're template control you simply put something like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```